# "Negative feedback warning" notification

Tags: policy, facebook-apps, facebook-insights, x-facebook-platform

I received a notification from Facebook "Negative Feedback Warning"

"Our systems have flagged your app # for receiving a high amount of negative user feedback. Accordingly, we might be forced to place a temporary restriction on your app in order to protect the user experience on Platform. We ask you to promptly address this issue within 48 hours of the sending of this notice, after which our automated systems will evaluate your app once again. Please note we reserve the right to take action against your app even before the end of this 48 hour period.
Specifically, users are responding negatively to Stream stories from their friends using your app."

I was not able to view the negative user feedback on either the app page or in Insights. How can I view the user feedback to understand the problem and address it.

Comment: Is your app still in development?

Comment: No, it is not in development and has been publicly available on facebook for more than a year

Answer (score 2):

The message explains the problem: Your app is making posts that users dislike. As it says, "users are responding negatively to Stream stories from their friends using your app".

Comment: My question is - "what is the negative response? Are they deleting the post or removing that privelege for the app or reporting the issue to FB as spam or something else? I also want to know if I can track the number of negative responses by category somewhere on FB Insights. "

Comment: removing permissions is not negative feedback.  Negative feedback is users blocking/hiding or uninstalling your application.   If you send out lots of apprequests and the majority of them get denied/ignored that is negative user feedback.

Comment: I found the FB Insight reports for Negative feedback. Click on "publish Category" on the left navigation. The thurd chart provides the number of story hides, spam reports and spam reports bby posting user. Now, the question is why did we get this notification even though these numbers have not changed significantly over the last month.

Comment: Probably because they were bad last month too.